# predic_proba output is a list of dict's: How to extract only the probaibility of been 1?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'0':0.0, '1':1.0},
 {'0':0.3333, '1':0.666}]
```

This is the output of a predict_proba method.

Now I want to pass do a dataframe the proba of be '1' only.

In scikit I do:

```
df['proba'] = model.proba[:,1]
```

The `[:,1]`means I want to pass the probability of been 1

How can I do the same with this list of dict's?

Comment: Post a [mcve] and include software version numbers. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values by using the list comprehension described [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-values-of-a-key-in-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python), and  assign the desired values to a new column.

```
values_of_key = [a_dict[a_key] for a_dict in list_of_dicts]
```

This gets you a list of only the desired values. You can then assign this list to a new column.